# google maps with d3 paths as a layer using (d3 v4)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following code which take a google map and then append a layer over it but there is a problem in the projection which gives me an error for it and don't show the layer on google map alone ,any help would be appreciated. 
note that I am using version 4 of d3.
any suggestion ?

```
<script>
    var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.5852,36.2384),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP });

 d3.json("Export.json", function(error, jordanLevel2) {
      if (error) throw error
      var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

      overlay.onAdd = function() {

        var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div");

        overlay.draw = function() {

          layer.select('svg').remove();

          var w = 900;
          var h = 900;


          var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

          // Turn the overlay projection into a d3 projection
          var googleMapProjection = function(coordinates) {
            var googleCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0]);
            var pixelCoordinates = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(googleCoordinates);
            return [pixelCoordinates.x, pixelCoordinates.y];
          }

          var path = d3.geoPath().projection(googleMapProjection);


          var svg = layer.append("svg")
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h)

          var g = svg.append('g')
            .attr("id", "mapGroup");


          g.selectAll("path")
            .data(jordanLevel2.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr('class', 'state selected')

            .style('opacity', .7);

        }
      }
      overlay.setMap(map);

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

Providing your code above works with D3 v3, what you need to do is replace the `googleMapProjection` function with the following `d3.geoTransform` function:

```
transform = d3.geoTransform({point: function(x, y) {
                  d = new google.maps.LatLng(y, x);
                  d = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
                  this.stream.point(d.x, d.y);
                }
              });
```

then, replace the `path` variable with:

```
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(transform);
```

**Explanation**

I think you're aware of the changes made in v4 that Mike Bostock has explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43653768/d3-js-changes-from-path-area-in-version-2-to-version-4/43661134#43661134) in response to a somewhat related question. Specifically, since this is a planar transformation (because we're converting latitude/longitude coordinates to pixels), we need to use `d3.geoTransform()`.

In both v3 and v4, we're taking a function where the inputs should be the lat/long coordinates* of the outline of the overlay shape that you're trying to plot on top of the google map. The function then converts these to pixel positions within the svg overlay using the `fromLatLngToDivPixel` method as before, and the `projection.stream` method then passes these values back to the path object, which is then called when plotting the overlay.

As far as I can tell, the differences between v3 and v4 here are:

1. You can't use the fallback projection, and so you have to use the [projection.stream](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#streams) method instead.
2. The replacement for the `googleMapProjection` function, `transform` takes the x and y coordinates individually rather than together within a single array.

**or relative coordinates, e.g. with topojson*