# D3.js - Changes from path.area in version 2 to version 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson, cartogram

I am trying to update [d3-cartogram](https://github.com/shawnbot/topogram) to work with D3.js version 4. So far, everything is going fine — I've just been updating all the functions so that they're written in the flattened namespace of version 4. For example, instead of `d3.geo.path()`, it's `d3.geoPath()`. I've also changed a few small things so that the code works with the latest version of [TopoJSON](https://github.com/topojson/topojson). For example, instead of `topojson.object(topology, geom).coordinates`, it's `topojson.feature(topology, geom).geometry.coordinates`.

But I've encountered a problem I can't seem to solve. The file `cartogram.js` has a line that reads `var areas = objects.map(path.area)`, where `objects` is a collection of TopoJSON Features. `path.area` is different in D3.js versions 2 and 4, and I can't seem to reconcile them. If I console log it in each version, it looks like so:

- Version 2: `function (n){return n&&e.hasOwnProperty(n.type)?e[n.type](n):t}`
- Version 4: `function (t){return U_(t,r(Ag)),Ag.result()}`

In version 4, it logs the error: `Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function`. Naturally, I've already Googled the error along with various descriptions of what I'm trying to do, but I haven't had any luck. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Helpful hint, load the *non-minified* version of `d3` for better insight into your error...

Comment: Harry, did you eventually create a working version of `d3.cartogram` for `D3.js` version 4?

Comment: Nope not yet. Got busy on other stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mark suggests, you should use non-minified code for debugging. The relevant non-minified code from [path/index.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/v1.6.3/src/path/index.js#L23-L26) looks like this:

```
path.area = function(object) {
  stream(object, projectionStream(pathArea));
  return pathArea.result();
};
```

Your error says that `projectionStream` is not a function; it’s probably undefined. The projection stream is set by [*path*.projection](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#path_projection), and as the documentation says, the *projection* you specify must implement [*projection*.stream](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#projection_stream). (This error is not enforced greedily when you set the *projection*. It is lazily thrown when you try to use the *path*.)

The problem here is that D3 3.x’s *path*.projection supported the concept of a “fallback projection”, which was just a bare function taking a longitude-latitude array as input, and returning an x-y array as output. D3 3.x would implicitly wrap this in a default projection object to add features like adaptive sampling and antimedirian cutting. D3 4.0 removed this feature, forcing you to be explicit: you must implement the *projection*.stream to use d3.geoPath.

Per [CHANGES](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#geographies-d3-geo):

> “Fallback projections”—when you pass a function rather than a projection to [*path*.projection](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#path_projection)—are no longer supported. For geographic projections, use [d3.geoProjection](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoProjection) or [d3.geoProjectionMutator](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoProjectionMutator) to define a custom projection. For arbitrary geometry transformations, implement the [stream interface](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#streams); see also [d3.geoTransform](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoTransform).

Whenever you ask for help, I recommend linking to a live example that demonstrates your issue, since a small snippet of code and description is often insufficient to isolate the problem. Here it’s unclear what *projection* you are trying to use with d3.geoPath. For planar transformations, you most likely want to be use d3.geoTransform or d3.geoIdentity. For spherical-to-planar projections, you’ll want to use d3.geoProjection or d3.geoProjectionMutator.